# Classic Sci-fi Movie depicting human slaves on a foreign planet wearing metal (dog like) collars that prevent them from leaving

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

Looking for a classic sci-fi movie (B/W?) depicting human slaves (a male and female) on a foreign planet wearing metal (dog like) collars that prevent them from leaving.

Comment: Can you remember roughly when you watched this/how old it roughly is? Can you remember any of the plot? What are they doing as slaves? Do they eventually escape? What do the aliens look like? If you have any more details to add, please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Are they control collars (technological) or just physical identification/restraints?  Are the slaves dressed as though they belonged to a technological society (i.e. mass-produced clothes, footwear) or low-tech (i.e. bare feet and rags)?

Comment: If animated see fantastic planet

Comment: This is a very common theme and I would guess that slave collars are very, very ancient and signify. I was thinking the STOS Triskelon episode is yet another show that might be what you are looking for. It also was the first TV show with cryptocurrency. I sure wish I had bought some quatloos in the 1960s.

Comment: I saw this movie circa ~ 70s but I am sure its older than that, perhaps 50s or 60s.? It's not Planet of the Apes. There is one scene where I remember the Man slave pointing to some constellation in the sky telling the girl slave that's where he was from. The collars prevented them from leaving the slave area. It's also not animated.

Answer (score 7):

Could this be the original (1968) [Planet of the Apes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_(1968_film))?

It fits in that

1. It ostensibly happens on another planet
2. Humans are enslaved by apes
3. The main character (and the other troublesome humans) are fitted with a collar
4. The main character ends the movie having escaped with a woman

[image: Planet of the Apes poster]